# get sql query from collection model

Tags: mysql, magento, model

I know that we can get sql query from magento model collection using this,

```
getSelect();
```

But I can get query from only the model collections, not worked in others or May be I dont know how to use it.

Here I want to know what query is running behind this,

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("color");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    echo $color_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText("28");
}
```

If I use this,

```
echo $productModel->getSelect(); exit;
```

I'm just get the one part the query only, like,

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
```

**Update:**

This is my full code,

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("color");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $color_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText("28");
}


$productModel->printlogquery(true);exit;
```

Please help me guys,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento collecting data with lot of internal queries - models and lot of checks, and may be more than 1 table.  So it is not possible to get the query like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your order condition is not visible in the query. The reason your order isn't showing is because the orders are added to the query during the load() method.

See `Varien_Data_Collection_Db::load()`

Try calling `load(true)` to see the complete SQL containing the order by clause.

```
$productModel->load(true);
$productModel->printLogQuery(true);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But Still I'm not able to get full sql query. I just got select query only (same before I got), like,

SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what is the exact query, then you can get this by using:

```
$productModel->printlogquery(true);exit;
```

Use this code after you have loaded your model's object and applied all conditions.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But Still I'm not able to get full sql query. I just got select query only (same before I got), like, SELECT e.* FROM catalog_product_entity AS e

Comment: Please put your code in your question, so that I can help.